Puppeteer web scraper inconsistent error: sometimes got undefined/null as page.evaluate() result
I'm trying to scrape data from a website using Puppeteer, the program was running in a loop with 30s interval between each execution. Sometimes it runs perfectly for around 1-3 iterations then out of nowhere getting null, other times it will get null straight away. Here's the error message

ERROR: The process with PID 56388 (child process of PID 89584) could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^


Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

let prevTx = [];

async function fetchLatestWallet(url) {
    const walletBrowser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
    });
    const walletPage = await walletBrowser.newPage();
    await walletPage.setUserAgent(generateRandomUA());

    await walletPage.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", });

    console.log("domloaded!");

    await walletPage.waitForSelector('tr[data-row-key="1"]');
    console.log("tr is detected");

    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);

    let firstRowData;

    await new Promise( async ( resolve, reject ) =>
    {

        firstRowData = await walletPage.evaluate( () => {
            const firstRow = document.querySelector('tr[data-row-key="1"]');
            const signature = firstRow.querySelector('a[href^="/tx/"');
            const name = firstRow.querySelector('span.ant-typography.ant-typography-ellipsis.ant-typography-single-line');
            const link = firstRow.querySelector('a[href^="/token/"');
            const amount = firstRow.querySelector('span.sc-kDvujY');
            return [signature.textContent.trim(), name.textContent.trim(), link.getAttribute('href').slice(7, link.getAttribute('href').length), amount.textContent.trim()];
        });

        resolve(await walletBrowser.close());
    });


    console.log("Wallet Fetching Result: " + firstRowData);

    let message = "";

    if(!prevTx || prevTx[0] !== firstRowData[0])
    {
        prevTx = firstRowData;
        message = message + prevTx[1] + ", " + prevTx[2] + ", " + prevTx[3];

        channel.send(message);
    }

    console.log(message);
}

Here's how the function being called
client.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    
    setInterval(() => fetchLatestWallet(neurl), interval[Math.floor(Math.random() * interval.length)]);
});

Please excuse my messy code, my 2nd time coding in javascript
I suspected that it might be the website preventing scrapping so I tried to randomize my userAgent every iteration and randomize my interval but still no solution.

Please provide a [mcve]. It seems one of your selectors is returning null, causing your evaluate to throw. How to solve it depends on the particular page you're manipulating and your underlying goal. You could use signature?.textContent.trim() and so forth, but this will give you a bunch of undefineds which will need to be handled. See also What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?--you can totally remove await new Promise( async ( resolve, reject ) => along with resolve().
